# Got a few problems with phpstorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm trying out the program the first time and I get errors and warnings that should not be there. because the page loads up just fine. I have screenshots.
**categories.php**

```
Undefined variable '$connection'
Path 'inc/header.php' not found
Path 'inc/nav.php' not found
Path 'inc/footer.php' not found
```

are the ones I'm talking about
[cat.php screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6t5l.png)

**db.php** screenshot
the warrings are valid code.
[db.php screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfZq5.png)

**header.php** is valid too
[header.php screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGhxp.png)

**Refactoring** seems to be not working I provided a screenshot
[Refactoring screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brMa0.png)

and is there a way to fix a code typo automatically or to see how it should be spelled?

Comment: The title of this question will not do a good job of connecting researchers with the specific scope of this question (questions).

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab at some of the issues in your [cat.php screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6t5l.png) of `C:\wamp64\www\CMS\admin\categories.php`

- **line 5** (path not found) The *relative* path in your include resolves to
  `C:\wamp64\www\CMS\admin\inc\nav.php` since "categories.php" is in the "admin" directory. And phpStorm is correct: that
  file does not exist.  Change line 5 to say `include __DIR__ . '/../inc/nav.php`
  I suspect that is the same issue with the header include on line 1 and the href links your `header.php` file.
- **line 15** (wrong attribute value) - method should be "post" or "get" (typically)
- **line 18** (missing associated label) - Add an `id=cat-title` attribute to your `<input>` tag.
- I don't have enough info to comment on the other issues

Comment: Once the include problem is solved, PHPStorm will realize that the `$connection` variable was defined elsewhere and stop complaining.

To stop this particular complaint without actually fixing anything, one could also specify that the variable *does* exist by adding at the top of the file, `global $connection;`